# CSS & SVG animation

Tags: html, css, svg

I am working on a button hover effect. I have managed to get it to animate on hover, however I am struggling to reverse the animation.

I have tried changing the stroke array and offset but neither seems to work effectively.

Here is my markup:

```css
    .btn {
     background: #e02c26;
       font-weight: 100;
       color: #fff;
       cursor: pointer;
       display: inline-block;
       font-size: 16px;
       font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 45px;
       margin: 0 auto 2em;
       max-width: 160px;
       position: relative;
       text-decoration: none;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       vertical-align: middle;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .btn span {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
    }

    .btn svg {
       height: 45px;
       left: 0;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       width: 100%;
    }

    .btn rect {
       fill: none;
       stroke: #565656;
       stroke-width: 2;
       stroke-dasharray: 422, 0;
    }

    .btn:hover {
       background: rgba(225, 51, 45, 0);
       font-weight: 900;
       letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    .btn:hover rect {
       stroke-width: 5;
       stroke-dasharray: 15, 310;
       stroke-dashoffset: 48;
       -webkit-transition: all 1.35s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
      transition: all 1.35s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
    }
```

```html
    <a href="#" class="btn">
        <svg>
         <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </svg>
        <span>Hover</span>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the transition on the **.rect** and not on hover, because if you set it on hover, the transition only works on mouse enter and not on mouse out,

But if you set it on the **.rect** it will work both ways .

Set the transition  in `.btn rect {...}`  instead of  `.btn:hover rect {...}`

**See code snippet:**

```css
.btn {
  background: #e02c26;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin: 0 auto 2em;
  max-width: 160px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn svg {
  height: 45px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn rect {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #565656;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-dasharray: 422, 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.35s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transition: all 1.35s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.btn:hover {
  background: rgba(225, 51, 45, 0);
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.btn:hover rect {
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-dasharray: 15, 310;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">
  <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </svg>
  <span>Hover</span>
</a>
```